# Is the expected conditional survival related to the hazard function?

Tags: probability

Survival function $S(x)$. Conditional survival function $\frac{S(x+t)}{S(t)}$, given that $X>t$.

The expected conditional survival of $X$, with $X>t$, should be given by $E(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{S(x+t)}{S(t)}dx$.

Is $E$ related to the hazard function $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{S(x)}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X|X>t]&=\int_\Omega X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}_{\{X>t\}}(\omega)
\\&=\int_{\{X>t\}}\dfrac{X(\omega)}{\mathbb{P}(X>t)}d\mathbb{P}(\omega)
\\&=\dfrac{1}{\mathbb{P}(X>t)}\int_\Omega\mathbb{1}_{]t,+\infty[}\big(X(\omega)\big)X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)
\\&=\dfrac{1}{\mathbb{P}(X>t)}\int_t^{+\infty}xf(x)dx
\\&=\dfrac{\mathbb{E}[X1_{\{X>t\}}]}{S(t)}
\end{align*}

While $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{S(x+t)}{S(t)}dx=\int_t^{+\infty}\dfrac{S(x)}{S(t)}dx=\int_t^{+\infty}\dfrac{\mathbb{E}[1_{\{X>x\}}]}{S(t)}dx\overset{Fubini}{=}\dfrac{1}{S(t)}\mathbb{E}\Big[\int_t^{X}dx\Big]=\dfrac{\mathbb{E}[X-t]}{S(t)}$

So the two quantities are generally not equal.

For the case of the hazard function, we have proven that:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X|X>t]=\int_t^{+\infty}x\dfrac{S(x)}{S(t)}h(x)dx
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the time until an event. In the context of survivability, $X$ is the time until death.

Given $S(x) = P(X > x)$ and

$$S(x+t|X>t) = \frac{S(x+t)}{S(t)} = \frac{P(X>x+t)}{P(X>t)}$$

Then,

$$E(X) = \int x f_X(x) dx = \int S(x) dx$$

$$E(X|X>t) = \int x f_{X|X>t}(x) dx =  \int x f_{X}(x|X>t) dx = \int_{x=t}^\infty  x\frac{P(x < X <x+dx)}{P(X>t)} $$

The hazard is

$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{S(x)}$$

and

$$h(x)dx = \frac{f(x)}{S(x)}dx = \frac{P(x < X< x+dx)}{P(X>x)}$$

$$E(X|X>t) = \int_{x=t}^\infty \frac{P(X>x)}{P(X>t)}dx = \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{P(X>x+t)}{P(X>t)}dx = \int_{x=0}^\infty  (x+t)\frac{P(x +t < X <x +t+dx)}{P(X>t)} $$

https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s1

I don't immediately see how to write $E(X|X>t)$ as a function of $h(x)$ except that

$$\Lambda(t) = \int_0^t h(x)dx$$

and

$$S(t)=\exp(-\Lambda(t))$$

so that

$$E(X|X>t) = \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{ \exp(-\Lambda(t+x)) }{ \exp(-\Lambda(t))}dx =  \int_{x=t}^\infty \frac{ \exp(-\Lambda(x)) }{ \exp(-\Lambda(t))}dx =  \int_{x=t}^\infty { \exp(-(\Lambda(x)+\Lambda(t))) }dx$$

$$E(X|X>t) = { \exp(\Lambda(t))} \int_{x=t}^\infty { \exp(-\Lambda(x)) }dx $$